# Java-Selenium: Eclipse is unable to find my file, but my file is in its working directory

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, fileinputstream

I am using Eclipse and the Java Library: java.io.FileInputStream;

My script cannot find a file that I want to assign to a variable using the constructor FileInputStream even though the file is in the Working directory.

Here is my code:

```
package login.test;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
public class QTI_Excelaccess {
        public static void main(String [] args){

        //verify what the working directory is
        String curDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
        System.out.println("Working Directory is: "+curDir);

        //verify the file is recognized within within the code
         File f = new File("C:\\\\Users\\wes\\workspace\\QTI_crud\\values.xlsx");
            if (f.exists() && !f.isDirectory()){
                System.out.println("Yes, File does exist");
            } else {
                System.out.println("File does not exist");
            }

        //Assign the file to src
        File src = new File("C:\\\\Users\\wes\\workspace\\QTI_crud\\values.xlsx");
        System.out.println("SRC is now: "+src);

        //Get Absolute Path of the File
        System.out.println(src.getAbsolutePath()); 


        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(src);

        }*
```

My output is (when i comment out the last line) is

"Working Directory is: C:\Users\wes\workspace\QTI_crud
Yes, File does exist
SRC is now: C:\Users\wes\workspace\QTI_crud\values.xlsx
C:\Users\wes\workspace\QTI_crud\values.xlsx"

When I don't comment out the last line, I get the error:

"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    Unhandled exception type FileNotFoundException

```
at login.test.QTI_Excelaccess.main(QTI_Excelaccess.java:30)"
```

Where have I gone wrong in my code?  I'm pretty new to Java

Much thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Major problem with the code is that you after you know that file do not exist on specified directory, you tried to read the file. Hence, it is giving you the error.

Refactor it to this

```
if (f.exists() && !f.isDirectory()){
        System.out.println("Yes, File does exist");
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
            //perform operation on the file
            System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath()); 
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("File does not exist");
    }
```

Here as you can see, if file exists then you try to read the file. If it is not available you don't do anything.

Comment: Thanks Jigar, adding the catch-file-exception worked and the script is now compiling.  The Java syntax rules take some getting used to,

Comment: Yeah. It takes some time to learn java. Within few months you will be good in java.